# Create default Paperclip image and associate it with different model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

In my Rails app I have two models: Ad and Picture with as has_many/belongs_to relationship. I use this setup to be able to have many pictures associated with one ad.

When users add pictures by themselves via the form everything works fine but I'm not able to add the default picture in case they don't upload anything. How would you do that in my case?

This is my Ad model:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :municipality
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 5..150 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { in: 60..2500 }
  validates :municipality_id, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  def self.search(query)
    if Rails.env.development?
      where("title like ?", "%#{query}%")
    else
      # Case insensitive search for PostgreSQL
      where("title ilike ?", "%#{query}%")
    end
  end

end
```

This is my Picture model with Paperclip configuration:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ad
  has_attached_file :pic, styles: { medium: "300x300>", big: "1000x1000>" }, default_url: "/images/default.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :pic, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

This is the create action of my Ads controller:

```
def create
  @ad = current_user.ads.new(ad_params)
  if @ad.save
    params[:pictures].each { |pic| @ad.pictures.create(pic: pic) } if params[:pictures]
    flash[:success] = "Die Anzeige wurde erfolgreich erstellt!"
    redirect_to @ad
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end
```

I thought this might work:

```
def create
  @ad = current_user.ads.new(ad_params)
  if @ad.save
    if params[:pictures]
      params[:pictures].each { |pic| @ad.pictures.create(pic: pic) }
    else
      @ad.pictures.create # Add default image to @ad
    end
    flash[:success] = "Die Anzeige wurde erfolgreich erstellt!"
    redirect_to @ad
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end
```

but this is the result:

```
#<Picture id: 64, pic_file_name: nil, pic_content_type: nil, pic_file_size: nil, pic_updated_at: nil, created_at: "2015-02-17 15:23:03", updated_at: "2015-02-17 15:23:03", ad_id: 52>
```

Comment: What did you expect ? You are not providing any information about the picture you want to create in your statement :  @ad.pictures.create

Comment: What information do I have to provide in order to use the default image?

Comment: I wouldn't save the default image in the database. What you want is if there aren't any pictures just display `Picture.new`. You can do that in your view (probably too messy), create a view helper, or add a method to `Ad` that returns either its `Picture`s or `Picture.new`.